# Си. Двухпутевое слияние. В чем ошибка?

Tags: c, сортировка, сортировка-слиянием, merge

В чем ошибка?Почему возвращается огромное значение и программа завершается досрочно?Выдает Segmentation fault , как это исправить?Или ошибка в самой сортировке?Подскажите пожалуйста.Заранее благодарю.

и сразу спрошу..как вычислять временную сложность такой сортировки?Как сравнения считать, вроде понятно..Но обмены ведь мы не совершаем..т.е. считать действия, когда мы переписываем элементы в массив "c"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void merge(int *a, int n){
    int mid = n / 2; 
    if (n % 2 == 1)
    mid++;  
    int *c = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int i = 0; int j = mid ; int k = 0;
    while(i<mid && j<=n){
        if (a[i]>a[j]){
            c[k]=a[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        else if (a[j]>a[i]){
            c[k]=a[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else {
            c[k]=a[i];
            c[k+1]=a[j];
            k=k+2;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (i<mid){
        while (i<mid){
            
            c[k] = a[i];
            i++; k++;
        }
    }
    if (i<=n){
        while(i<=n){
            c[k] = a[j];
            j++; k++;
        }
    }
    

}
void arrprint(int *arr, int n) {
    printf("%d", *arr);
    int i;
    for ( i = 1; i < n; i++) printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    puts("");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int n = 10;
    int *arr;
    arr = malloc(n * sizeof *arr);                    
    srand(time(NULL));
    int s;
    for ( s = 0; s < n; s++) {
        arr[s] = rand() % 50;
    }
 
    arrprint(arr, n);  
    merge(arr, n);
    arrprint(arr, n);  
 
    free(arr);                                       
 
    puts("");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: тяжело пока понять алгоритм. пока непонятки в последнем цикле : `while(i<=n){
            c[k] = a[j];
            j++;` индекс `i` не трогается. и непонятки с массивом `c` : он не используется вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, `n`-го элемента же в массиве нет, поэтому к нему обращаться нельзя.

Во-вторых, массив-приёмник `c[]` никак не используется

В третьих. это не сортировка, а только слияние двух частей массива, и должны быть заданы границы  этих частей, например `merge(int *a, int n, int mid)`

Сам код слияния может выглядеть так:

```
while(i<mid && j<n){
        if (a[i]<=a[j])
            c[k++]=a[i++];
        else 
            c[k++]=a[j++];
    }

while (i<mid) 
   c[k++] = a[i++];
while (j<n)
   c[k++] = a[j++];
```

[Вот сортировка](http://algolist.manual.ru/sort/merge_sort.php)  (там стоит подправить сравнение `if (a[pos1] <= a[pos2])`)